# Darker Edges on my mesh that mess up my Subdivide mod

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, subdivision-surface, topology

I have a Deformed Cone object.

I have extruded it (part that sticks out on the left). The rest of the mesh, including the other extrusion, is fine for the most part but this just looks horrid.

Lines / Creases that mess up my Sub divide mod:

[image: Image of the Lines / Creases that mess up my Sub divide mod]

In the mesh these show up as darker edges. I am wondering how I get rid of this so my object looks nice and smooth under the modifier.

Image of the object's Mesh

[image: Image of the object's Mesh]

Image of the entire object

[image: Image of the entire object]

It's worth noting that I have tried to merge by location but the option to merge does not show up, I also checked my normals.

Is this just an issue with the placement of my vertices?

Comment: Please show your work in wire frame mode as well.  Make sure you have smooth shading. Make sure you do not have coincident edges. (Failed extrusions can cause this)You should look at how many corners have 5 edges and how many corners have 4.  Some 5 poles are necessary and the result of extrusion.  Make sure you do not have unnecessary  5 poles. Try not to get quads in the that look like long triangles You can search for Model Topology for lengthy explanations.

Comment: Archive your file or scene if necessary. If the original mesh has a small time investment then   try a second time. The second time may have reduced mistakes.  Fresh Start.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger by going through each stage of your answer I fixed my problem, thank you. It turns out the problem was making a quad out of a neccessary 5 pole.

Comment: @FinleyQuayle if you solved the issue, please write an answer to your own questsion and explain clearly what you did. Other users with similar issues can learn from you.

Comment: @FinleyQuayle its always interesting when someone tells you to post an answer ... yet they have provided no candidate help or ... upvoted you.  Though mathematically I do not know that with certainty. Yet at the time of this writing you have 15 view.  I do not need an answer from you but if you are finished with this task I might want to have a reminder.  The choice is entirely yours.